# $2$ linear transformations with different kernels of the same dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The question is: "Give $2$ linear transformations $\varphi, \psi$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, where their kernel's dimensions are the same, but they are different subspaces in $V$."

I assume that \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix} and \begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix} matrices are appropiate matrices, but how can I show, that they're really correct? I know that they're dimensions are the same, but how can I show, what is their kernel? And are these matrices really different subspaces?

Comment: What do you mean they are correct ? Also a matrix is not a subspace.

Comment: I mean that these matrices belong to linear transformations

Comment: but I'm pretty unsure how to solve it

Comment: All matrices represent a linear transform. And solve what ? You need to be precise.

Comment: Where is Germany are you ? I am in Berlin.

Comment: Hi, I've edited your question a bit so that the whole question isn't in the title, it's not what the title is there for.

Comment: I live in the near of München

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, let $\varphi: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2, \varphi(x) := \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix} = (a, a + b)$.

Then $ker(\varphi) = \{ x \in \Bbb R^2 : \varphi(x) = 0 \} = \{ (a, b) \in \Bbb R^2 : (a, a+b) = (0, 0) \} = \{(0,0)\}$. Similarly you can check $ker(\psi) = \{(0,0)\}$.

So, yes, $dim(ker(\varphi)) = 0 = dim(ker(\psi))$ but unfortunately $ker(\varphi) = ker(\psi)$ also holds.

Please note that if you pick a matrix with nonzero determinant then $Ax \ne 0 \forall x \ne 0$, so it won't really help you.

Comment: so do I have to find a matrix with a nonzero determinant? but can be the dimension of the kernels be equal?

Comment: If $det(A) \ne 0, det(B) \ne 0 \implies ker(A) = \{0\} = ker(B)$. What should be your approach then?

Comment: if I take:$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$

$ \psi: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2, \zeta(x) := \begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix} = (a+b, a + b)$

$ker(\zeta) = \{ x \in \Bbb R^2 : \zeta(x) = 0 \} = \{ (a, b) \in \Bbb R^2 : (a+b, a+b) = (0, 0) \} = \{(0,0)\}$

Comment: @Zauberkerl a) what is $\zeta$? b) assuming $\zeta = \psi$ then it's false. $ker(\zeta) = \{(x, -x): x \in \Bbb R\}$ c) you still need another linear transformation to complete the exercise

Comment: could you maybe help me by giving two appropiate matrices?

Comment: try with $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}$